# Which camera module will interface with STM32F7 Disco board?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, camera, stm32f7

Which camera module will interface with [STM32F7 Disco](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/LN1848/PF261641#) board? The connector on the board is a 30-pin FPC/FFC 0.5mm.

Could the [OV2640](http://www.arducam.com/camera-modules/2mp-ov2640/) be adapted for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [STM32F7 User Manual](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00190424.pdf), page 16:

> A connector P1 with the DCMI signals is available to connect a camera module such as STM32F4DIS-CAM (ST order code)

So the camera module that recommended by manufacturer is STM32F4DIS-CAM, see this [ST page](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/LN1199/PF255417?s_searchtype=keyword), [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?WT.z_cid=sp_497_0928_buynow&Enterprise=44&lang=en&Vendor=497&mpart=STM32F4DIS-CAM), or other distributors.

For your questions:

> Could the OV2640 be adapted for this?

I think the answer is Yes. There are many projects on the web that connecting OV2640 to STM32 family module, for example [this with DCMI](http://www.elektricks.net/ov2640-camera-module-under-chibios-on-the-stm32f4-discovery-board/) or [this without DCMI](http://qyx.krtko.org/projects/ov2640_stm32/).